# Action Listeners and inner classes java

Tags: java

So I have a nested class in my public static void main. It seems to compile and be correct but the function it is supposed to perform doesn't seem to execute.  Here is the method.

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{

  LevelOne l = new LevelOne();
  //Level Two not made yet just a place holder to show constructor with a different type
  LevelTwo l2 = new LevelTwo();
  //I make l2 first because the front frame is the last one created
  Main m = new Main(l2);
  Main m2 = new Main(l);
  //To switch levels i am going to load them all in advance and then when the beat the level it will close the frame

  class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
  {
      Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
      //timer is used for the actionlistener
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
   {
    if(l.checkWin())
   {
     m2.setVisible(false);
     m2.dispose();
    }
   }

    }

  }
```

And here is the variable it is supposed to access form level l in the other class.

```
public void setWin()
{
   this.checkWin = true;  
}

public boolean checkWin()
{
  return this.checkWin;  
}
```

checkWin is a private instance field for the other class. For some reason when checkWin is set to true it still wont execute. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Main is also the name of the class thats why the constructors say main sorry if there was any confusion because of that.

Comment: Where are you creating instance of your listener class and using it ?? You merely declared it as of now.

Comment: Are these Java Swing/AWT controlls? Because if they are, I think I already know what's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in main method

```
Timer tm = new Timer(5, new ChoiceListener());
tm.start();
```

and remove

```
Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
```

from `ChoiceListener`. Also move `ChoiceListener` out of main method in the class so that it can be instantiated using class instance or make it static so that it can be directly instantiated.

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't seem to work. I mean it compiles but it still doesnt seem to execute. It might be something related to my other class but any other ideas.